# How to put multiple objects in one array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to put multiple objects in one array in javascript?

I have n json strings like this:

```
first object
'[{"name":"1","position":{"x":-28.890169060450745,"y":-89.45,"z":103.39384013230637},"property":{"floor":"Platform", "name":"1"}]'

second object
'[{"name":"2","position":{"x":-28.890169060450745,"y":-89.45,"z":103.39384013230637},"property":{"floor":"Platform", "name":"2"}]'

third object
'[{"name":"3","position":{"x":-28.890169060450745,"y":-89.45,"z":103.39384013230637},"property":{"floor":"Platform", "name":"3"}]'
...
nth object
```

Here I want to put n obejects into one result

like this

```
'[{"name":"1","position":{"x":-28.890169060450745,"y":-89.45,"z":103.39384013230637},"property":{"floor":"승강장","name":"1"},
[{"name":"2","position":{"x":-28.890169060450745,"y":-89.45,"z":103.39384013230637},"property":{"floor":"승강장","name":"2"}],
[{"name":"3","position":{"x":-28.890169060450745,"y":-89.45,"z":103.39384013230637},"property":{"floor":"승강장","name":"3"}]'
```

For this, I tried the following, but if I push it, it comes into the Array itself.

```
for (let i = 0; i < DataList.length; i++) {
    if (i == 0) {
        mergetData = JSON.parse(DataList[0]);
        continue;
    } else {
        mergetData.push(JSON.parse(DataList[i]));
    }
}
```

I am wondering how can I solve this problem.

Best Regards!

Comment: You are actually looking for is how to merge multiple json string into one javascript string.

Comment: Your desired result isn't valid JSON, it has unmatched `[`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse all the JSON arrays, then concatenate them into a single array.

```
let parsedData = Datalist.map(s => JSON.parse(s));
let mergeData = [].concat(...parsedData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are asking how to put multiple objects in one array but your desired output is the string object. So I'm considering your desired output as the actual question :)

For that you just have to iterate through your `DataList` and merge values into an string object.

```
StringObject = ''
for(let i=0; i < DataList.length; i++){
    if(i===0)
        StringObject += DataList[i]
    else
        StringObject += ',' + DataList[i]
}
console.log(StringObject)
```

Or just

```
StringObject = String(DataList)
console.log(StringObject)
```